# Sequenced jQuery code

Tags: jquery

How would i sequence the following code so one line runs after the previous ?

```
$('#jqNav li a').click(function(e){

    if($(this).parent().is(".nav1")){ $('.landing .main .nav ul').css({ "background-position" : "0 -50px" });} 
    else if($(this).parent().is(".nav2")) { $('.landing .main .nav ul').css({ "background-position" : "0 -100px" });}
    else if($(this).parent().is(".nav3")) { $('.landing .main .nav ul').css({ "background-position" : "0 -150px" });}
    else if($(this).parent().is(".nav4")) { $('.landing .main .nav ul').css({ "background-position" : "0 -200px" });};

    stopAnim = true;
    $page = $(this).attr('href');
    var $hashTag = $(this).attr('name');
    window.location.hash = $hashTag;
    loadData();
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would already bind the ajax call inside of the loadData block to a method on success. I have fabricated and tested (FF 5.0 & IE 9) the following code snippet and the success method is called (you need to create the 'test.html' file):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function()
{
    $('a').click(function()
    {
        loadData();
        return false;
    });

    function loadData()
    {
        $.ajax({
          url: "test.html",
          context: document.body,
          success: loadDataSuccess()
        });
    }

    function loadDataSuccess()
    {
        alert('success!');
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="bla.html">Test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The only thing I noticed was that 'e.preventDefault' would not stop me from following the link so I changed that to 'return false'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `loadData()` is triggering an asynchronous AJAX request, your problem will only be how to defer the final:

```
$(window).scrollTop(0)
```

until after the new content is loaded.

The best way to handle that will be for `loadData()` to return a handle to the AJAX request, and then use:

```
loadData().done(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

which uses the deferred object syntax introduced in jQuery 1.5

Comment: That did not work i used jquery 1.5.1, and it also broke e.preventDefault();

Comment: did you change `loadData()` to return the `jqXHR` object?  You must have triggered an exception for it to have stopped `e.preventDefault()` from being called.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out .queue() if you're looking to do animations.

http://api.jquery.com/queue/

From what I understand you're trying to run set these in order upon success?

```js
        $('#jqNav li a').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).parent().is(".nav1")) {
            $('.landing .main .nav ul').css({
                    "background-position": "0 -50px"
            });
    }
    else if ($(this).parent().is(".nav2")) {
            $('.landing .main .nav ul').css({
                    "background-position": "0 -100px"
            });
    }
    else if (
    $(this).parent().is(".nav3")) {
            $('.landing .main .nav ul').css({
                    "background-position": "0 -150px"
            });
    }
    else if ($(this).parent().is(".nav4")) {
            $('.landing .main .nav ul').css({
                    "background-position": "0 -200px"
            });
    };
    e.preventDefault();
    stopAnim = true;
    $page = $(this).attr('href');
    var $hashTag = $(this).attr('name');
    window.location.hash = $hashTag;
    $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            success: function (e) {
                    $(window).scrollTop(0);
                    // Run your scripts to occur after ajax success in here
            },
            error: function (e) {
                    console.log('error occured');
            }
    });
```

});